# Comentarios de revisión en preguntas y respuestas

Tags: discusión

Puedo ver en esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/58799/78) que las revisiones hechas por otros usuarios respecto a la calidad de la respuesta de un usuario generan comentarios automáticos de revisión, pero me pregunto *(tal vez solo sea yo)* que al ver y leer los comentarios un usuario "especialmente nuevo usuario" se sienta algo abrumado y pueda ser interpretado como "hostilidad" o algo diferente a lo que claramente se puede leer.

Mi pregunta es, ¿hay algún cambio que se pueda aplicar a la funcionalidad de revisión, por ejemplo, para evitar que se apliquen mas de un comentario de revisión?

Adjunto captura de pantalla *(solo en caso de que sean eliminados los comentarios)*:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

<sub>No necesariamente esto tiene que ser un problema, pero me gustaría leer la opinión de usuarios quienes hayan recibido comentarios de aquellos usuarios cuyas preguntas, respuestas y comentarios hayan sido revisados.</sub>

Comment: Yo creo que al ver más comentarios agregados se puede sentir abrumado por el contenido de ellos. Me parece que si fuesen más asertivos y que inciten a la búsqueda de mejora en lugar de ser un poco agresivos podrían ayudar más.

Comment: Por ejemplo "Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta" podría redactarse como "En su estado actual, la respuesta luce más como un comentario". Así también, "Mejor es proveer respuestas que no requieran clarificación (...)" podría ser "Resulta más efectiva que las respuestas sean claras, concisas y auto contenidas".

Comment: @Luiggi Me encantaría ver eso como una propuesta separada en meta (lo charlamos hace mucho y quedó ahí). Realmente me parece totalmente necesario ese cambio... Creo que una discusión en meta para evaluar un mejor texto tendría el apoyo de la comunidad, y luego se podría formalizar como propuesta. En serio, estaría genial si lo publicaras... Es momento de ajustar estas últimas tuercas flojas!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Una opción que encuentro válida es seguir estos pasos:

1. *Si existe un comentario que resalte el motivo del reporte/mejora a la pregunta/respuesta*, **vote (upvote) ese comentario** para así resaltarlo por cantidad de votos de comentario.

   1.1 *Al seleccionar el motivo de cierre* de la pregunta/respuesta/comentario, seleccione la opción:

> No se necesitan comentarios

2. *Si el comentario no existe*, seleccione el motivo del reporte según se muestra en la captura de pantalla - *según sea el caso*.

---

Captura de pantalla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Gracias al [comentario de Mariano](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1654/comentarios-de-revisi%C3%B3n-en-preguntas-y-respuestas?cb=1#comment4710_1655):

> Cabe aclarar que cuando el motivo de eliminación es el mismo que otro
>   ya emitido, el texto no se repite, sino que automáticamente se le da
>   un +1 al comentario previo.

Entiendo que no hay necesidad de generar una mejora en la funcionalidad existente.

Comment: Cabe aclarar que cuando el motivo de eliminación es el mismo que otro ya emitido, el texto no se repite, sino que automáticamente se le da un +1 al comentario previo.

Comment: @Mariano, he editado mi respuesta, pero creo que tu comentario sobre la aclaración de - Cito: `cuando el motivo de eliminación es el mismo que otro ya emitido, el texto no se repite, sino que automáticamente se le da un +1 al comentario previo` debería ser una respuesta. Lo curioso para mí es que los comentarios de revisión hechos por otros usuarios "como se ve en la captura de pantalla" se repiten, por lo que no se si es un bug o una funcionalidad que no conozca.

Comment: gracias por editar la respuesta aclarando... En la captura Rene Limon votó por "únicamente un enlace", y A. Cedano votó por "comentario sobre otra publicación". No hay mensajes repetidos.

Comment: @Mariano, tienes razón. Debo revisar mejor :)